# How to convert column type from int64 with decimal to numbers without decimals in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm working on a year column where is contains values such as 2014.0 , 2016.0 ...etc and i want to convert these numbers to integer but they are stored as int64 pandas data frame and i got this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b17dd2133d2a> in <module>
      8 
      9 
---> 10 df1['Année'] = df1['Année'].apply(remove_decimal)

4 frames
<ipython-input-44-b17dd2133d2a> in remove_decimal(x)
      5         return 0
      6     else:
----> 7         return int(str(x).rstrip(".0"))
      8 
      9 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

```
def remove_decimal(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return 0
    else:
        return int(str(x).rstrip(".0"))

df1['Année'] = df1['Année'].apply(remove_decimal)
```

I tried this code but it gives the error.
I also tried this code but nothing chnges df1['Année'] = df1['Année'].astype(int, errors='ignore')

Answer (score 1):

One idea is use `try-except` statement:

```
def remove_decimal(x):
    try:
        return int(str(x).rstrip(".0"))
    except AttributeError:
        return 0
```

Or:

```
def remove_decimal(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except AttributeError:
        return 0
```

Another is replace missing values to `0` and then convert values to integers:

```
df1['Année'] = df1['Année'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

If there are some non numeric values like `''` and need convert it to `0` use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df1['Année'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['Année'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
```